# How to catch a part of regex but with some requirement in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

sorry, I confused how to search in search engine about what I want to find the answer...

What I want is catch and replace a part of string with regex, but with requirements, And the requirements is not included to the result. Here for example:

I want to replace an @ (at) sign  with no backslash before...

If I use "string".replace(/[^\\]@/g) it will also replace the character
before at sign, except it is back slash...

more information with same destination with the example before
string.replace(/[^\\]@/g,"Replaced");

- abc\@ still kept as abc\@    (What I want)
- abc@ replaced as abReplaced (I want this **NOT** occured)
- abc@ replaced as ab**c**Replaced (What I want, the character before @ not replaced, the c character)

  So the conclusion is Every @ sign with backslash before it will NOT be catched/Replaced, But if it has no backslash before, it will be catched/replaced with before character of the@ sign not be catched/replaced

Comment: Single `\` means that `[^\]` it has to begin with ] because \ breakst ] it has to be \\

Comment: Your three examples are _very_ unclear.  I don't see any obvious pattern there.  Your verbal description sounds nice, but the text doesn't support it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general answer to this question in regular expressions is you would use a *negative look-behind assertion*. But JavaScript doesn't have lookbehind.

In your case, you can just capture the character before (if any) and re-output it as part of the replacement:

```
result = string.replace(/(^|[^\\])@/, "$1Replaced");
```

(The `^|` part is to allow for no character before, e.g., beginning of string. The `|` is an *alternation*, e.g., `^` **or** `[^\\]`.)

(If you want to do it globally, you'll also want the `g` flag.)

Also note that to use a literal backslash in a regular expression, you must escape it (with another backslash).

Examples (using `g` for global replace):

```js
function test(string) {
  console.log(string, "=>", string.replace(/(^|[^\\])@/g, "$1Replaced"));
}
test("abc\\@");
test("abc@");
test("@abc@abc");
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it with a capture group and put `$1` in the replace argument to reproduce that character:

```js
var res = 'abc@'.replace(/([^\\|^])@/g, '$1Replaced');

console.log(res);
```

Note that you need to cover for the possibility that `@` is the first character of your string, and in that case your regular expression will not have a match. Solve this by matching as alternative with the start of the string (`^`).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```js
const data = [
  'test@asd.cs',
  'test\\@asd.asdf',
  '@test\\@asd.asdf'
]

const removeAtSymbol = str => str.replace(/([^\\])@|^@/g, '$1')

for (const item of data){ 
  console.log(item, '->', removeAtSymbol(item))
}
```